# How to evaluate this integral $\int_{1/3}^{3} \frac{\sin(\frac1x -x)dx}{x}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int_{1/3}^{3} \frac{\sin(\frac1x -x)dx}{x}.$$

I am unable to think of any way to solve this.

Comment: It's zero, isn't it?

Comment: Following on the hint from @LordSharktheUnknown, try the substitution $u=\log x$.  Then the integral of an odd function over an interval symmetric about the origin is $0$.  Any time $dx/x$ appears in an integral $u=\log x$ is worth considering as a substitution.

Comment: Yes it is zero.

Comment: @sharding4 what is a symmetric interval about zero? Can you give me a useful link where I can read up the statement you mentioned regarding integrals of odd functions

Comment: No.  The integral after the substitution goes from $u = \log 1/3$ to $u = \log 3$ which is symmetric by basic rules of logarithms.  

$\int _{-a}^{a} f(x) dx =0 $ whenever $f(x)$ is an odd, integrable function.  That's usually just an exercise in any calculus text.

Comment: @sharding4 got it

Comment: When seeing $\frac 1x-x$ inside the integral and $3,\frac 13$ for the bounds in an apparently unsolvable calculation you must think *hey! maybe there is a symmetry that makes it 0...*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint. Note that by letting $t=1/x$, we get
$$\int_{1/3}^{3} \frac{\sin(\frac1x -x)dx}{x}=\int_{3}^{1/3} 
\frac{\sin(t-\frac1t)(-dt/t^2)}{1/t}=-\int_{1/3}^{3} 
\frac{\sin(\frac1t-t)dt}{t}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Enforce the substitution $x=\frac{-t+\sqrt{t^2+4}}{2}$, which is equivalent to $t=\frac{1}{x}-x$.  Then, we have $dx=\frac12\left(-1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}\right)\,dt$ and

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1/3}^3 \frac{\sin\left(\frac1x-x\right)}{x}\,dx&=\int_{8/3}^{-8/3}\frac{\sin(t)}{\frac{-t+\sqrt{t^2+4}}{2}}\,\left(-\frac12+\frac{t}{2\sqrt{t^2+4}}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\int_{-8/3}^{8/3}\underbrace{\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{t^2+4}}}_{\text{an odd function}}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^3 \dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)}{x}dx=\underbrace{\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^1\dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)}{x}dx}_J+\underbrace{\int_1^3\dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)}{x}dx}_H$$
$$J=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^1\dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)}{x}dx\quad t=\dfrac{1}{x}\rightarrow x=\dfrac{1}{t}\rightarrow dx=-\dfrac{1}{t^2}\quad \text{and}\quad \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x=\dfrac{1}{3}\rightarrow t=3 \\
             \\ x=1\rightarrow t=1 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
$$J=\int_3^1\dfrac{\sin \left( t-\dfrac{1}{t}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{t}}\left( -\dfrac{1}{t^2}\right)dt=-\int_1^3\dfrac{\sin \left[ -\left( \dfrac{1}{t}-t\right) \right]}{-t}dt=-\int_1^3 \dfrac{-\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{t}-t\right)}{-t}dt=$$
$$=-\int_1^3\dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{t}-t\right)}{t}dt=-\int_1^3\dfrac{\sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x}-x\right)}{x}dx=-H\rightarrow I=-H+H=\boxed{0}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\displaystyle I =\int^{3}_{\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{x}\cdot \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x}-x\bigg)dx$

put $x=e^t,$ Then $dx = e^t dt$ and changing limits

So $\displaystyle I = \int^{\ln(3)}_{-\ln(3)}\underbrace{\sin (e^{-t}-e^t)}_{\bf{odd\; function}}dt =0.$